# Refresh value of GridView, which is populated by SQL Data Source

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, gridview, datagridview

i am populating the values on page load to grid view using SQLDataSource. i am able to see all the values properly. now i have also added a check box column as template field. So, if i check the check box in front of the row it is removing the that row from database but still i am able to see that same row in grid view. Now if i refresh the page that values are gone (as the query worked without any error) but i dont want to refresh the page on every entry. I want to refresh the grid view on button click. 
i tried GridView.Update()cand gridview.refresh but both the functions are throwing run time error.
refer below code.

```
int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                CheckBox CH = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("CheckBox4");
                Label DebitSrNo = (Label)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("Label2");
                Label DebitDate = (Label)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("lblDebitDate");

                if (CH.Checked == true)
                {
                    for (j = 0; j < GridView2.Rows.Count; j++)
                    {
                        CheckBox CreditCheckBox = (CheckBox)GridView2.Rows[j].FindControl("chkCreditBalance");
                        Label lb1 = (Label)GridView2.Rows[j].FindControl("lblSrNoCredit");
                        Label CreditDate = (Label)GridView2.Rows[j].FindControl("lblCreditDate");
                        if (CreditCheckBox.Checked == true)
                        {
                            if ((Convert.ToDateTime(CreditDate.Text) > Convert.ToDateTime(DebitDate.Text)))
                            {
                                string query = "UPDATE [BALANCE_CREDIT] SET STATUS = 1 WHERE SR_NO = {sr_no}";
                                query = query.Replace("{sr_no}", lb1.Text);
                                SqlConnection conn = OpenDBConnection();
                                int AffectedRows = 0;
                                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                                AffectedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                query = "UPDATE [BALANCE_DEBIT] SET STATUS = 1 WHERE SR_NO = {sr_no}";
                                query = query.Replace("{sr_no}", DebitSrNo.Text);
                                cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                                AffectedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                CloseConnection(conn);
                                GridView1.Rows.Remove(2);//here it is giving runtime error. so as for update and refresh
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Without question you are going to have a problem on the line … `GridView1.Rows.Remove(2);` … the problem is that this line of code is “inside” the … `for (i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)` … loop! … Unless the code does some kind of “special” juggling of the `i` index (which is NOT recommended) … the loop is going to fail somewhere down the line if you “remove” some of the rows. If you have to remove the rows… then I suggest keeping track of those rows, then remove them “outside” the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The last line where your are getting a runtime error

```
 GridView1.Rows.Remove(2)
```

change it to

```
GridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(j);
```

it will work.

Comment: As your code says there are two datagridview. Can you please confirm in which gridview you want to delete record?

Comment: if you want to delete in gridview1 so may this code work                                                                         
         **GridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(i);**